# passing variable value in subprocess.run python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

How do I call this variable `sd_namesp` in subprocess run ?
when I try to do this using below method, I get invalid syntax
I also tried `f"{sd_namesp}"` that doesn't works either

```
for seccontent in sec_ver_data:
    sd_namesp = seccontent.get("name") + seccontent.get("ition") + str(seccontent.get("version")
    largs = ['java','-jar','cli.jar','n','-cf', config_path, '-r', seccontent.get("reg"), '-n', seccontent.get("name"), '-i', seccontent.get("sid"), '-f', sd_namesp]
    lresp = subprocess.run(largs, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
    print(lresp.stdout)
print("end")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting a syntax error because it looks like you forgot to close your parenthesis here:

`sd_namesp = seccontent.get("name") + seccontent.get("ition") + str(seccontent.get("version"))`

Notice the extra parentheses at the end.